# Issue Creating PrivateFontCollection from Resources

Tags: c#, .net, privatefontcollection

I've been running this same code for months and it's worked like a charm.  Recently, I've had this code added to source control in TFS and it's no longer working properly.  The only changes were to modify some namespaces to meet our product guidelines.  The purpose is to create a `pfc` out of fonts that are embedded as resources in the file - the reason being that the executable is to be portable and not rely on anything aside from appropriate an .NET version being installed.

```
    public static Dictionary<string, object> FontDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public static PrivateFontCollection s_FontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
    public static Font staticFont;

    public static FontFamily[] FontFamilies
    {
        get
        {
            if (s_FontCollection.Families.Length == 0)
                LoadFonts();

            return s_FontCollection.Families;
        }
    }

    public static Font GetFont(string family, float size)
    {
        foreach (FontFamily font in FontFamilies)
        {
            if (font.Name.ToLower().Equals(family.ToLower()))
            {
                Font ret = new Font(font, size);
                //return (Font)ret.Clone();
                return ret;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void LoadFonts()
    {
        if (Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() == null || Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames() == null)
            return;

        foreach (string resource in Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames())
        {
            // Load TTF files from your Fonts resource folder.
            if (resource.Contains(".Fonts.") && resource.ToLower().EndsWith(".ttf"))
            {
                using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // create an unsafe memory block for the font data
                        System.IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)stream.Length);

                        // create a buffer to read in to
                        byte[] fontdata = new byte[stream.Length];

                        // read the font data from the resource
                        stream.Read(fontdata, 0, (int)stream.Length);

                        // copy the bytes to the unsafe memory block
                        Marshal.Copy(fontdata, 0, data, (int)stream.Length);

                        // pass the font to the font collection
                        s_FontCollection.AddMemoryFont(data, (int)stream.Length);

                        // close the resource stream
                        stream.Close();

                        // free up the unsafe memory
                        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(data);
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        FontDict.Clear();
        FontDict.Add("SYS",    new Font("Arial", 20));
        FontDict.Add("SYSs",   new Font("Arial", 14));
        FontDict.Add("MICR",   GetFont("MICR", 18));                    // Preferred MICR font
        FontDict.Add("SIG",    GetFont("PWSignaturetwo", 30));
        FontDict.Add("HAND1l", GetFont("Daniel", 22));
        FontDict.Add("HAND2l", GetFont("Jenna Sue", 32));
        FontDict.Add("HAND3l", GetFont("Honey Script", 30));
        FontDict.Add("HAND4l", GetFont("Confessions", 42));
        FontDict.Add("HAND5l", GetFont("Soljik-Dambaek", 26));
        FontDict.Add("HAND6l", GetFont("Billy's Hand Thin", 38));
        FontDict.Add("HAND7l", GetFont("Daisy Script", 34));
        FontDict.Add("HAND8l", GetFont("Fineliner SCript", 34));
        FontDict.Add("HAND9l", GetFont("Graphe", 20));
        FontDict.Add("HAND1s", GetFont("Daniel", 16));
        FontDict.Add("HAND2s", GetFont("Jenna Sue", 26));
        FontDict.Add("HAND3s", GetFont("Honey Script", 24));
        FontDict.Add("HAND4s", GetFont("Confessions", 30));
        FontDict.Add("HAND5s", GetFont("Soljik-Dambaek", 20));
        FontDict.Add("HAND6s", GetFont("Billy's Hand Thin", 26));
        FontDict.Add("HAND7s", GetFont("Daisy Script", 26));
        FontDict.Add("HAND8s", GetFont("Fineliner Script", 26));
        FontDict.Add("HAND9s", GetFont("Graphe", 14));
        FontDict.Add("HACKs",  GetFont("Hack", 10));                    //******************************************************//
        FontDict.Add("HACKm",  GetFont("Hack", 12));                    //    Preferred fixed-width font for non-check data     //
        FontDict.Add("HACKl",  GetFont("Hack", 16));                    //******************************************************//
```

What suddenly has started happening is that all fonts don't get loaded to the dictionary.  As far as I can tell while debugging, the resources are fine.  It loops through all of the font resources correctly.  However, when it gets to `s_FontCollection.AddMemoryFont` it starts skipping some.  I was trying to figure out how to read the `Status` return value from the method ([as noted here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534175(v=vs.85).aspx)) but can't seem to make that work.  I've honestly changed no other code related to this.

The really odd part is it's an issue at the time of execution.  I can run the same build multiple times and end up with different results regarding what fonts are available.

Comment: Sure, it has a time-bomb that's ready to go off at any second.  Today is your lucky day, calling Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem() is a bug.  You must leave the memory allocated until you can no longer use the font.

Comment: I wondered about that, but my understanding was that once the font bytes were in the collection it no longer needed the pointer.  It's also odd that this has never been a problem before.  Is there a better way to create the pfc from embedded resources so that they are always available?

Comment: PrivateFontCollection has a Dispose() method, you are supposed to call it and *then* you can release the memory.  You probably never call it, almost nobody does, which is okayish because it is hard to do so but just don't call FreeCoTaskMem() either.

Comment: @HansPassant - That doesn't resolve the issue either.  It's not even a matter of using the font.  The font doesn't get built into the pfc even before FreeCoTaskMem() is being called.  The resource is seen, it steps through LoadFont with that font, gets to AddMemoryFont() and doesn't add it to the pfc.  But not always.  And not always the same fonts.  On a single run of the executable, if all fonts come in properly (even with FreeCoTaskMem()) they are always available through the life of that process.  If on another run one is missing, it's always missing.

Comment: Never use an empty `catch` clause, you'll have no idea what went wrong and we don't either.  At the very minimum catch Exception and use Debug.WriteLine() so you know what happened.  But realistically you must remove try/catch completely or your user has no idea why "it doesn't work" either.  Exceptions are your friend, they tell you why your program doesn't work.  Don't hide them.

Comment: I would agree with that, but no exception occurs - it simply isn't added to the pfc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was a ttf file that went corrupt when it was added to source control.  As to the discussion above, deallocating the memory via FreeCoTaskMem() works fine (as it always did previously) because it's only needed temporarily to get the bytes to memory so that AddFontFromMem() can be utilized - which is the easiest way to get embedded data into the pfc.  Removing the errant font resolved the issue entirely.